# Shutter Priority Mode - Purple Photos

Tags: canon, shutter-priority

When taking photos using a Canon Digital Rebel XS in shutter-priority mode and experimenting with very fast shutter speeds, the photos are usually dark as I expect, but occasionally the photos will appear as shown below:

[image]

Is this an artifact of the ISO being too low for the shutter speed, or is there something else going wrong with the camera?

Comment: An original Canon EOS Digital Rebel (300D)? Or one of the almost endless other Rebel models that have followed?

Comment: @MichaelC Sorry, should have been more specific. It's a Canon Digital Rebel XS, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Assuming we are looking at a photo of a [tiki torch](https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/0378fdd3-d6e7-4d65-9d19-1e1b24370e0b/svn/tiki-citronella-torches-131720568-4f_600.jpg) these colours are certainly not a result of a camera setting or an expected artifact. It seems that something is getting corrupted. It could be your camera (as it's from [2008](https://global.canon/en/c-museum/product/dslr798.html)) or your SD card. Do you have another SD card you can try out?

Comment: looks like a bad/crooked/failing memory card to me. Is that from a raw or jpeg image?

Comment: "an artifact of the ISO being too low for the shutter speed"... that simply results in underexposure. Why would underexposure add strange purple colours to an image?

Comment: What is your primary light source? More specifically, is it an LED light source?